# Boolean Type Conversion Systems (Java)

Tags: java, javascript, php, templates

I am considering a type conversion system for a flexible template system. I need to map any object types to meaningful boolean values to ease flexibility and usability.

There are many things to consider and we love working systems, so we look at existing solutions first.

In PHP for example the following conversion system for boolean exists:

Things are considered (boolean) true if not:

- false (boolean)
- 0 (integer, long, short, byte, BigInteger)
- 0.0 (float)
- "" (String)
- empty array
- empty collection or map
- null

Now the question goes if this a good system? What other rules do other system use? What are the drawbacks of this one?

I am currently also considering this system:

Everything is false except:

- true (boolean)
- 1 (number)
- "true" (String)
- not null (Object)
- non-empty array or Collection or Map

It's quite easy, too.

[Update]

To give you additional information. The template system is developed in Java and is related to Web components. It features a script language like OGNL that has additional capabilities like invoking methods, accessing special features provided by the environment like plug-able helper methods and macros).

It uses a custom type conversion system simply converting a result from one type (Class) to another (other Class). Therefore it forms a simple two dimensional matrix for every allowed type conversion. One can add many converter to a single combination but there is no guarantee which one is used.

Today I think about the map anything towards Boolean.class alternatives. Having used several scripting languages myself, I wonder what different approaches are existing, what are the pros and cons of each of it regarding readability and expressivness and simplicity.

[/Update]

Comment: In  e.g. JavaScript falsy values are `false`,`0`,`""`,`null`,`undefined`,`NaN`. Any value, not being falsy is considered truthy

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `Java`? Java has no such conversion system, and by looking your at list for PHP and your own consideration, I still feel happy with Java having neither.

Comment: The target language is Java so by adding the Java tag I hoped for additional considerations like already existing solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic conversion to boolean can be seen as a variant of the “special value means failure” idiom. This is very error prone as different operations use different values for such a purpose as the range of valid return values differs. It’s always dangerous to design a programming language with only one use case in mind…

Let’s start with you first example (php):

- 0 means false: well, most `indexOf` methods (Collections, Strings, …) return `-1` for “not found” while zero is a valid value. The same applies to `InputStream.read`
- 0.0 (float) means false: that’s almost never useful. There’s `NaN` for the really absent value while zero is a valid result too often and there’s no reason to make it more special than `+4.9E-324`.
- "" (String) means false: look at `BufferedReader.readLine`: an empty `String` is a valid value when reading a text file. `null` marks the end of file.
- empty array, empty collection or map: conflicts with the next item
- null means false: if `Collection`s and `String`s were something special being not an object, it could be useful but having rules that change when using a sub-class is not a good idea. And of course, there are situations where `null` is a valid value and you have to look at exceptions or a special error variable instead.

Regarding your consideration:

> Everything is false except:
>
> - true (boolean)
> - 1 (number)
> - "true" (String)
> - not null (Object)
> - non-empty array or Collection or Map

Do you know any Java API where one, and only one, is the indicator of success and every other value a failure? It looks like there’s no use for this rule at all. Almost similar thing for the `"true"` String. Besides system properties, no one returns a `String` of `"true"` where (s)he could just return the boolean value `true`. Not to speak about the case sensitivity issue or the question, why not accept "yes", etc. And it conflicts with the non-`null` rule you consider afterwards. Makes it a difference if I cast a `String` to `Object` before applying the automatic boolean conversion? Same ambiguity for the array/collection rule.

---

There might be languages where a carefully chosen automatic conversion that is in sync with the library of that language produces convincing results. But I never saw one. All languages which support such conversion have their pitfalls or “don’t use when…” rules. And if you want to bind *Java* to your script language it’s even less likely to have a benefit that outweighs the risks for errors. The Java API is designed to be used with a language without such an automatic conversion feature.

Comment: The API is String centered since it is working heavily with text. Therefore contributing a string "true" is a necessary feature. I currently think of just introduce a well described macro function like isTrue(string/object/collection) that aids with this kind of handling and leave the "true" recognition out of it. I will also add isAlmostTrue(float) to allow Fuzzy logic mapping.

Comment: To BufferedReader that is true. There is a hasNext() method missing to overcome this line != null test. It is a relict of '95.

Comment: That’s always something with relicts. As I said, a system carefully designed from the ground may overcome this problem. But in practice it’s like php: kludged in the 90s, offering APIs which are relicts of the 70s, and still being buggy in 2013. And you plan to bind the script language to Java (as far as I understood) so you are entering into the same problems. For your own library there’s no such problem. It might be `String`-centered without such problems by having its own special type under the hood which is convertible to `String` and `boolean` at the same time.

Comment: I am free to start fresh and I am in total control of the API which is being exposed and made available. So I am totally free in that regard.

But from all these information the best I can do is start using methods and predicates instead of build in support. It simple reads better if you have something like: <li if="isTrue(operations.current.status)">...</li>. I decided that we can build in additional out of the box support for special conversion if the need is apparent or the user start to complain about verbosity or unwanted repetition.

Answer (score 0):

As per My understanding, I hope this will helps you.

There is nothing wrong. it is only depends on your requirements.

1. In some cases, -1 is return by objects where the specified items are
   not present in the collection List.
2. any how the programming languages follows some standards which is still followed from low
   level languages like assembly level.
3. Because all higher level languages are converted to machine level languages during execution / compilation. In this scenario the existing system will reduce some complexity while converting the high level code.

**Solution I recommended**

In your case you can use conditional operators for example,

**PHP**

```
1. $is_tested = ($tested=="Completed") ? TRUE : FALSE; 
2. $is_tested = ($tested=="TRUE") ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

**JAVA**

```
1. boolean is_tested = (tested=="Completed") ? TRUE : FALSE; 
2. boolean is_tested = (tested=="TRUE") ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Comment: I 'll add some more information to the question. The idea is having a matrix of potential converters converting from one type to another. I am currently considering the BooleanConverter that maps any thing interesting towards a boolean value (needed for if, ifNot etc).

So I just need an overview of existing mappings in other script languages and programming languages to consider alternatives and see if I can avoid mistakes by overlooking something important here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have not much knowledge in java.

In IBM WEB-Sphere,
The Conversion of types between PHP and Java

Even I suggested you to refer IBM WEB-SPHERE for type conversion.
Here is a [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsmashin/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.sMash.doc/using/zero.php/TypeConversion.html)

I hope this may help you and give some more idea.